# Proper way to deal with POST requests in JavaScript Firebase apps?

Tags: javascript, post, firebase, http-post, firebase-hosting

I'm creating a Firebase web application with HTML/JavaScript, preferably using Firebase hosting. A 3rd party source needs to send my application a POST request. How can I deal with this such that I don't need a backend aside from Firebase?

I know JavaScript can't typically access the POST data sent to the web server. Does Firebase hosting have a mechanism to expose that data to JavaScript? Is there another way? How do others create Firebase JavaScript apps that deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the third-party service can send the POST as JSON data, you can direct it to Firebase's [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) and just have your client listen on the appropriate path for POST events.

```
curl -X POST -d '{
  {
    "name": "Alan Turing",
    "birthday": "June 23, 1912"
  }
}' 'https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/foo/.json'
```

And on the client:

```
firebase.database().ref('foo').on('child_added', function(ss) {
   console.log('third party service contacted us', ss.val());
});
```

If the third-party service cannot send JSON formatted data, then you'll need a server to intercept the post requests and either reformat them to json (probably simplest) or to talk to the client directly.

Comment: Nice one! I couldn't think of any way, but you clearly could. :-)

Comment: The 3rd party service redirects the user to our website through a POST (the user actually has to click a button and the `form` `action` points to our URL). If I could get the POST request as JSON data, would I be able to have Firebase redirect the user to our HTML page?